# Clone and Append a Div to a Div using Data Attribute

Tags: jquery, clone

Is this even possible?

My main div has a div inside, I cloned it and assigned a unique data attribute to each cloned element. These cloned divs have divs inside, and I want them to be cloned too. So, how will I do it using `.clone()` and  `.appendTo()` methods?

Here are some parts of my code:

```
<div id="card_grid">
   <div class="cards_slot" data-unique="0" id="cards_slot">
      <div class="play_cards"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery, JavaScript:

```
//Clone the card slots
for(var i=0;i<=18;i++) {
    $(".cards_slot:first-child").clone().appendTo("#card_grid");
}

//Initialize the cards slots' position
$("#card_grid").children().each(function(index) {
    $(this).css({
        "left" : ($(this).width() + 50) * (index % 5),
        "top" : ($(this).height() + 20) * Math.floor(index / 5)
    });
    var child_position = ($(this).parent().children().index(this));
    var element_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var new_id = element_id + child_position;
    $(this).attr('id', new_id);

     $(this).attr('data-unique', child_position);
});
```

Comment: When you clone an element it's children are cloned too. Inspect the DOM and you will see the cloned _empty_ div descendants.

Comment: @undefined, Yes. What I actually want to do is clone the div inside the div that I have cloned.

Comment: and whats the point ? the selector ?

Comment: The structure of my code is wrong. I supposed to clone the inner div first (children), then clone the outer div (parent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

```
var $toBeCloned = $(".cards_slot:first-child"); 

for(var i=0;i<=18;i++) {
    var $cloned = $toBeCloned.clone();
    $cloned.find('div:first').clone().appendTo($cloned);
    $cloned.appendTo("#card_grid");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3JSPc/